# How to set the Windows taskbar icon during runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

normally the icon that belongs to a application's taskbar-button is the same icon that is contained in the EXE and shown for the program. Now within my application I want to change this icon dynamically, means a configuration is read where a (PNG) image is specified. Now the application loads this image and has to set it as new taskbar icon.

But: how can this last step be done? How do I set the icon in taskbar (not in tray!) during runtime?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx

Comment: @MarkRansom: the Taskbar APIs do not allow you to change the icon of a Taskbar button.  Only the window that owns the button can specify its own icon.

Answer (score 5):

Send a [WM_SETICON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to your window, passing the size (either `ICON_BIG` or `ICON_SMALL`) in the `wParam` and the handle to the new icon in the `lParam`.

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIcon);
```

Comment: You need to use `SendMessage()` instead of `PostMessage()`.  And you do not need to type-cast the `wParam` parameter, just the `lParam`.  `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIcon);`

Comment: @Remy: Updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: OK, this does not work for me. Are there any special conditions for the format of the icon? I tried it with 32x32, 64x64 and 128x128 pixels, all 256 colours.

Comment: It works fine for me, and has for years. Have you tried with an actual icon file rather than a .PNG? I linked to the documentation for the message in my answer. I can't explain why it's not working for you, because I can't see your code or the images you're trying to load.

Comment: Ken White: It seems it is caused by the fact that the EXE contains an icon with different resolutions (16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 128x128,...). So when I set my custom icon Windows seems to decide to use an other of the original icons - but one with a different size.