# Dynamic taskbar icon depends on configuration of taskbar?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

I implemented the possibility to load a custom taskbar icon during runtime dynamically (according to [How to set the Windows taskbar icon during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039731/how-to-set-the-windows-taskbar-icon-during-runtime) ).

Now I noticed a strange behaviour: the new taskbar icon is set correctly, but Windows 7 still shows the old (original) icon when the "Taskbar buttons" in properties of taskbar are configured to "Always combine, hide labels". When choosing one of the other options the custom icon is shown.

So: any idea what causes this or how to overcome tihs problem? I want to show the custom icon in all configurations of taskbar.

Thanks!

Comment: When the (potentially different) icons of multiple windows are grouped together Explorer has to pick one to use; I guess it's picking the one from the executable itself. I doubt you can change this.

Comment: That is exactly what it does. And it gets even trickier when windows from multiple executables gets grouped together. Which exe does the icon come from?  Anyone's guess.

Comment: In my special case it also happens when they are not grouped and exactly one application of this type is started - so Windows would not have to choose from different icons, it is just one. Anyway, thanks for clarification :-)

Comment: This happens when "Always combine" option is set and the program shortcut is pinned to taskbar.