# How to specify title icon and dock icon separately in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm using the code below to specify the app icon. But that would change both the title and dock icons.

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QIcon icon(":res/image/my-icon.png");
app.setWindowIcon(icon);
```

Is there any way to specify them separately?

Comment: What OS it supposed to run on?

Comment: Windows for now.

Comment: I will look at my projects later but with Windows: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-windows

Comment: The link looks like to set an icon for the file. I'm trying to set an icon for the title bar while another one for the dock icon/taskbar icon.

Comment: If Qt does not satisfy then try OS API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039731/how-to-set-the-windows-taskbar-icon-during-runtime

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try.