# Possible for a Windows application to be programmed to allow the user to select minimized-state icon?

Tags: windows, user-interface, window, taskbar, minimize

Is it possible for a Windows (7/8/8.1/10) application to be programmed to allow the user to select an icon to be used for when the application is minimized to the Windows taskbar?

Any programming language is acceptable.

EDIT: I'm voting to self-close, as I think this is close enough to a duplicate to the question that Alex Weavers kindly provided.

Comment: Yup! Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039731/how-to-set-the-windows-taskbar-icon-during-runtime. You should be able to do it in most languages.

Comment: @AlexWeavers Thank you! That's wonderful news.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the Windows taskbar icon during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039731/how-to-set-the-windows-taskbar-icon-during-runtime)